# How to concatenate list of results from pandas.read_html

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am able to print/get to **CSV** dataframe from one URL using the code down below

```
import bs4 as bs
import pandas as pd

dfs = pd.read_html('http://www.url1.com',header=0)


for df in dfs:
    print(df.head())
df.to_csv('File.csv')
```

I would like is to concatenate multiple dataframes in one.

- dataframe1 from http://www.url1.com
- dataframe2 from http://www.url2.com
- ...
- dataframeN from http://www.urlN.com

Combine all the dataframes into a single one and export it to 'file.csv'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas.concat` to concatenate dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

urls = ['http://www.url1.com',
        'http://www.url2.com',
        'http://www.url3.com']

df = pd.concat([pd.concat(pd.read_html(url, header=0), axis=0) for url in urls], axis=0)

df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

---

**Explanation**

- `pd.concat` concatenates a list of dataframes.
- `pd.read_html` returns a list of dataframes.
- Therefore, to concatenates a list of lists of dataframes, i.e. a list of `pd.read_html` output, you need to use nested `pd.concat`.

Comment: As to solve the question it'll require to scrape (get the data) from every single one if `.read_html` works, great.We can then concatenate them using the method you've provided. Please make sure to include the code for writing it (data) to a file.

Comment: Thank you very much, but your code gives me an error :
`TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid`

So I have chaged the code into :

`import pandas as pd

urls = ['http://www.url1.com',
        'http://www.url2.com',
        'http://www.url3.com']

for url in urls:
    pd_read = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
    df = pd.concat(pd_read, axis=0)
    df.to_csv('file.csv')`

Comment: @prog-amateur, try update. Looks like `pd.read_html` returns a list of dataframes, so we might need nested `concat`.

Comment: Dear all, the code WORKS !!! Thank you so much. 
But as I am a beginner in data analysis and panda, I would like to know why nested `concat` make a dataframe while `concat` (once) make a list ? 

Thank you very much.

Comment: @jpp, Thank you so much for your quick feedback, very appreciated.